# How to use built-in PHP web server with spaces in custom root path

Tags: php, server

In Windows, I'm succesfully using PHP built-in web server with a custom path as a root folder and my own php.ini file using this command line:

`php.exe -S localhost:80 -t c:\custom\path -c php.ini`

But whenever the custom path has a space character it fails and the server refuses to initialize, so using 'localhost' as URL gives a connection timeout error. It works fine if no spaces in path name.

I've tried using quotation marks before and after the path name and also replacing spaces with `+` character or `%20` with no luck.

Not working samples:

`php.exe -S localhost:80 -t c:\my custom\path -c php.ini`

`php.exe -S localhost:80 -t "c:\my custom\path" -c php.ini`

`"php.exe -S localhost:80 -t "c:\my custom\path" -c php.ini"`

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Paths in windows, if they contain spaces need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: I've tried double quotes enclosing the path but it doesn't work, and even enclosing the whole parameter and the path in double quotes.

Comment: Could you update your question with the example of a path with spaces? Also please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Dharman, I have edited the content to clarify as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of arguments matter when starting PHP.exe
If you execute it with `-c` option before `-t` option it should work.
As for the path with spaces it needs to be enclosed in double quotes.

As an example this is what I tried on my local Windows machine:

```
php.exe -S localhost:80 -c php.ini -t "C:\xampp\htdocs\formatter - Copy\"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. I would have never thought about order of arguments importance.

Comment: I would love if someone could back me up on this claim or provide a link to PHP manual if it is documented somewhere.